# .NET Core - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use a custom DLL (4.5 framework) in a aspnet core 1.1 app.

I'm using `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility`

When I run the project and try to make a call at some class of the library project, vs2017 throw the following exception.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ApiHelperSock, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
```

If I check the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1` I can see my dll here.

This is my project.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas ?

--- EDIT ---

Tried to setup a nuget package with my dll, getting the following error when trying to import:

```
The package ApHelperSock 1.0.0 isn't compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). The package ApiHelperSock 1.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
```

Tried to create a .NETFramework library project, import here and then call the library from my aspnetcore app, without success.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no project.json in VS2017 ASP.NET core project template.

Comment: @Sanket: Well you can still open old projects old project.json projects in VS2017 when you open it as folder and not via *.sln/*.xproj, VS won't suggest that you migrate

Comment: And btw. the posted json file is not a `project.json`, it's a `tsconfig.json` which contains typescript options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't auto-magically use .NET 4.5 libraries in .NET Core applications! Your library has to target `netstandard1.0` or higher.

Convert your library to a `netstandard1.0` (4.5.2) or `netstandard1.2` (.NET 4.5.2) project. If you use .NET 4.5 only Api, you also need to add `net45`/`net452` target and use `#ifdef NET45` preprocessor directives to make your code inside it only compile for `net452`, but not for other platforms.

In .NET Core 2.0 you'll get the ability to reference normal .NET 4.5 libraries, but the same limitations apply and you must be extremely carefully when using it: It will **only then** work on .NET Core, **when the referenced library only uses API which is available on .NET Standard 2.0**!!!
Using **any other API** will blow up your program at runtime! This option is only there for people who need to reference a library which is .NET 4.5 but not yet ported for .NET Standard 2.0 (i.e. orphaned nuget packages).

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos ( commenting on my recent duplicate question )

> First, switch to .NET 6. .NET 5 reaches End Of Line on May
> 2022, 3 months away. .NET 6 is the Long Term Support version, with the
> new fully functional Windows Forms designer. Second, you can't use
> .NET Old code with .NET (Core) 5 or 6. You can't share any UI-related
> code, because .NET Old only supports up to .NET Standard 2.0, which
> doesn't support Windows Forms