# 'Could not load file or assembly', dll reference asp.net core 2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, asp.net-core, dll-reference

I'm having reference errors when running my asp core 2 web application. My web (core 2) project is referencing another (.dll output) project (.net 4.7) which has Windsor.Core and windsor.castle nuget packages installed. When running the web project, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Both projects are targeting x64 (needed for another library). The properties of the Windsor.Core and castle dll's:

[image]
[image]

The Windsor libraries are added to the .dll project only. When I also add the same nuget packages to the asp.net core project, the program crashes with following message:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IWindsorInstaller Castle.Windsor.Installer.FromAssembly.This()'.'
```

which to me, seems like only a part of the library is loaded.

Both Windsor.Castle / Core libraries can be found in the output directory of the asp.net core 2 web application. But why can't it find it?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771733/net-core-could-not-load-file-or-assembly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core - Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771733/net-core-could-not-load-file-or-assembly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User AsifAli72090 was right, I also thought something like that would be the problem but my google results didn't give me that answer.

I fixed the problem by creating a new .net **core** dll project in my solution and moved all of my files to there. You can google on how to convert to a .net core project, but it's not as easy as checking or switching a dropdown in the settings. Everything worked flawlessly then!